# Correct template for nested class C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, inner-classes

I can't figure out the correct syntax to write a correct template for a nested class. I'd like to do something like this

```
template <typename T>
class list {
private:
    class node {
    public:
        T value;
        node();
        ~node();
    };

public:
    node<T> *H;
    list();
    ~list();
};
```

I want to have a class to represent each element of the outer class, so I'd like to have the inner class to be hidden inside the outer. Is this possible? Or should I use a different approach?

Comment: You want to make the inner class a template too?

Comment: `node` is not a template. `node *H;` should work fine.

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, if you have a class with only public members, then consider using `struct` instead. A `class` and a `struct` is just the same, it's just the default visibility that's different (`private` for `class`, and `public` for `struct`).

Comment: Yes node should be a template class, but the type of the class should be the one specified during the declaration of list. If I write list<int> I want node to be of int type.

Comment: A `public` member of a `private` nested class? You will run into issues when some one tries to access `H` outside of `list<>`

Comment: Then just *make* it a template? E.g. `template<typename U> struct node { U value; ... }`? Not that it's needed.

Comment: @Some It's even easier. `node` doesn't need to be a template class itself.

Comment: what does "a class to represent each element of the outer class" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually what I was looking for was this.

```
template <typename T>
class list {
private:
    template <typename U>
    class node {
    public:
        U value;
        node();
        ~node();
    };

public:
    node<T> *H;
    list();
    ~list();
};
```

Comment: There is no reason for `node` to be a class template. As other answers have said, you can use `T` to create members inside `node`.

Comment: @JensB so what I was doing in the OP?

Comment: You were trying to declare a `node` pointer with a template parameter(`node<T>`) even though you didn't declare `node` as a class template. Just have `node`  be a normal class and declare one of its members as a `T`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to specify the template parameter for the inner class (because it isn't declared as template class):

```
template <typename T>
class list {
private:

    class node {
    public:
        T value;
        node();
        ~node();
    };

public:
    node *H; // <<<<<<
    list();
    ~list();
};
```

Comment: I think you should address that having a `public` member of a `private` nested class is not a good idea.

Comment: @muXXmit2X Clients can access it using `auto`.

Comment: I want it to be a template class to but I didn't know that I needed to put another template. The very first answer I got was the correct one but now it seems to be gone

Comment: @user0042 Oh did not know that.  For someone as uninformed as me [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/18wHsbWQOtFHFoCN) is an example accessing `H` using the `auto` keyword.